# SharePoint Site App Pools restarting outside of scheduled time

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-application

in our production environment (we are running SP 2010 Enterprise) I have noticed that we are starting to see the App Pool for the main SharePoint Web Application restart during the day.  These are scheduled to only restart during the night, in checking the Event Logs around the restarts I see error messages like the following:

> A process serving application pool 'Main_Site' suffered a fatal
>   communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '5212'. 
>           The data field contains the error number.

I am not finding anything in the ULS Log and wondering if there is a way to somehow get some other information on the crashes, there don't seem to be any dump files anywhere.  I think this is probably some sort of memory exception but I can't find anything in the existing logs that would actually confirm this for me.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try DebugDiag (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580960) to analyze this situation. Be very aware however that running DebugDiag and attaching it to you application pool will bring SharePoint performance almost to a halt.

Using DebugDiag you can save dumps of the SharePoint application pool in question and let DebugDiag analyze this. The tool knows about SharePoint and can analyze the dump file to see what might be going on.

A good getting started can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/09/06/capturing-a-memory-dump-using-debugdiag-1-2.aspx

Comment: Not a bad option but considering this is our production environment this would be really terrible to implement.  I'll keep it in mind as a last resort if I can somehow duplicate the conditions to generate the app pool restart then maybe this will get me the infomration I need.